# ☆と★と✔の違いを教えて下さい。

Tags: サポート

☆と★と✔の違いを教えて下さい。
参考ページを教えて下さい。
よろしくお願いします。

Comment: ご質問の意味がよく分かりません。このサイトで使われているマークということでしたら、スクリーンショットを添付していただけませんか？

Comment: ご質問ありがとうございます、そしてコメントもありがとうございますm_ _m。スクリーンショットをこちらの投稿に追加させていただいてもよろしいでしょうか？美しく貼れるかどうかは不明なのですが、追加することによってどの箇所のことなのかがクリアになると思いました⭐️✨

Answer (score 7):

☆と★はその投稿(質問)を「お気に入り」したかどうかを表します。質問を後からでもすぐに参照できるよう、星マークをクリックすると★(有効)、☆(無効)が切り替わります。
星の下の数字は何人がその投稿をお気に入り登録しているかの人数を表します。

✔は回答が質問者によって承認されたことを示すマークです。「回答に納得した」もしくは複数の回答が付いた場合に「一番参考になった」と思った回答に対して質問者のみが承認マークを付けることが出来ます。